# SQL left join with the same column

Tags: sql, left-join, self-join

I am currently trying to query a table such as this where the phases of a project and the dates of those phases are all in the same columns. The table is as follows:

| Project ID | Phase | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PR001 | Create | 1/1/2022 |
| PR001 | Approve | 1/2/2022 |
| PR001 | Implement | 1/3/2022 |
| PR001 | Close | 1/4/2022 |
| PR002 | Create | 1/2/2022 |
| PR003 | Create | 1/5/2022 |
| PR003 | Approve | 1/7/2022 |
| PR003 | Implement | 1/8/2022 |
| PR004 | Create | 1/3/2022 |
| PR004 | Approve | 1/6/2022 |
| PR004 | Implement | 1/7/2022 |
| PR004 | Close | 1/8/2022 |
| PR005 | Create | 1/9/2022 |
| PR005 | Approve | 1/9/2022 |
| PR005 | Implement | 1/10/2022 |
| PR005 | Close | 1/11/2022 |

I am hoping to query the table to get a list of each project with it's date approved and closed. If the project has not reached the approve phase yet, then it will not show in the table. If it has reached approve or implement but not close yet, it will show in the table the approve date and Null for the close date such as this:

| Project ID | Approve | Close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PR001 | 1/2/2022 | 1/4/2022 |
| PR003 | 1/7/2022 | Null |
| PR004 | 1/6/2022 | 1/8/2022 |
| PR005 | 1/9/2022 | 1/11/2022 |

I am trying to left join the table to itself, but when I do this I get duplicate rows of the project ID where the approve date is there and the closed date is null, then the approve date is null but the close date is there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Moving data between cells & column titles is "pivoting". PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that provides all the info while eliminating cases where `Approve is null`

```
select   [Project ID]
        ,max(case Phase when 'Approve' then [Date] end) as  Approve
        ,max(case Phase when 'Close'   then [Date] end) as  [Close]
from     t
group by [Project ID]
having   max(case Phase when 'Approve' then [Date] end) is not null
```

| Project ID | Approve | Close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PR001 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| PR003 | 2022-01-07 00:00:00.000 | null |
| PR004 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-08 00:00:00.000 |
| PR005 | 2022-01-09 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00.000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70a9f3e047cc9ba7a8667902673ec00f&hide=1)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  project_id,
  max(case when phase = 'Approve' then date end) as approve,
  max(case when phase = 'Close' then date end) as close
from t
group by project_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Seems like I was making it more complicated than necessary.